# Maximum consecutive subsequence

Tags: algorithm

Hello All
Please help with below algorithm,

Suppose we have sequence (negative numbers allow ) 4, 3, -2, 13, 11, 1, 1, 8, 5  i need to find 
subsequence with max sum between members,but also distance between members  should be 4 at least in original sequence.
according example subsequence will be (13,8)=21

Thanks for help.

Comment: I understand that you're not a native English speaker, but your question is very difficult to understand. Maybe you could try [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com). Also, you should provide specific doubts, and not expect someone to do your work for you. People are here to help, not to do your homework.

Comment: Your question is unintelligible. Please edit so that it makes sense.

Comment: If you can express your question clearly in your native language, there's a good chance someone here can edit your post to make it meaningful in English.

Comment: I think he wants the maximum sum subsequence that contains at least `k` elements. Not sure though. In the example, `k` is 4. @marcog - that is what you think the question is, not what it is. Please don't edit until the OP clarifies, you completely changed even what little was clear.

Comment: I hope I understood correctly (!), but I've edited the question to be more meaningful.

Comment: This edit confirms why I wanted to close it to being with. there is no effort shown, only "give me answers."

Comment: Voted to close. The original Q is not meaningful, and the edit, although meaningful, lacks the keyword "distance" that seems important in the original.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. He wants the maximum sum subsequence, except the subsequence is not really contiguous; we can skip elements as long as we skip at least 4 positions.

Comment: @IVlad Then the answer would be greater than 21. Perhaps *all* values selected must be at least 4 apart?

Comment: @marcog - yes, all of them. There shouldn't have been a "we can skip" in my comment, we HAVE to skip at least 4 positions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

So, you want the maximum sum subsequence such that any two elements `i` and `j` in the chosen subsequence have `j - i >= 4`. We can solve this with dynamic programming.

Let `a` be the given array.

Let `m[i] = maximum sum subsequence with the desired properties ending at position i`.

If we have

```
    1  2   3   4   5  6  7  8  9  
a = 4, 3, -2, 13, 11, 1, 1, 8, 5
```

Then

```
m[1] = 4 
m[2] = 3
m[3] = -2
m[4] = 13
m[5] = max(m[5 - 4 = 1] + 11, 11) = max(4 + 11, 11) = 15
...
```

In general, we have `m[i] = max{max(m[j] + a[i], a[i]), j = 1 to i - 4}`

This will be `O(n^2)`. You can get an `O(n)` solution from this pretty easily. Notice that it always helps to choose the maximum `m[j]` in the above recurrence. So, compute the maximum of `m` as you traverse it, like in the following pseudocode:

```
maxm = -inf
for i = 1 to a.Length do
    m[i] = a[i]

    if (i >= 4 + 1)
        if (m[i - 4] > maxm)
            maxm = m[i - 4]

        m[i] = max(m[i], maxm + a[i])


output the maximum value in `m`.
```

You can easily generalise this to `k` instead of `4`.

---

**This isn't what you want, but I'm leaving it anyway because I think it's an interesting variation on a classic problem**.

If you are indeed looking for the maximum sum subsequence with length at least `k`, then this algorithm will solve that problem in `O(n)`:

Let `a` be your array of numbers.
Let `s[i] = s[i - 1] + a[i]`. This is a called a **prefix sum array**. We can use this to find the sum of any sequence `[i, j]` like this: `sum[i, j] = s[j] - s[i - 1]`.

So, for each `i >= k`, we need a `j <= i - k + 1` such that `s[j - 1]` is minimum. Take the one which gives the maximum sum in the end.

```
s[0] = 0
for i = 1 to a.Length do
    s[i] = s[i - 1] + a[i]

max = -inf
min = inf

for i = k to a.Length do
    if (s[i - k] < min)
        min = s[i - k]
    if (s[i] - min > max)
        max = s[i] - min
```

Comment: Thank you for answer .The length of subsequence maybe any length,
Suppose the first member in subsequence have  1(first ) position ,the next member must have 1+k position in original sequence.
Where k>4
In example subsequence(13,8) we have  first member is 13 that have position 4 and 8 that have position 9
I hope it will help to understand problem.
I am trying to solve this with matrix array where each row contains best member’s positions, but I am stuck…

Comment: @Leo - I have updated my post, please reread it and see if the current solution is what you need, I think that solves what your problem asks for.

Comment: That's a philosophical question, not simpler than meaning of life. But good solution, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Without the "at least k elements" part, this is a classic problem: www.codemanic.com/mathnotes/papers/maxsum/MaxSum.pdf

Comment: Thank you for comment, actually it is not really same problem.

Comment: @Leo Please clarify your question then.